# How to find the image plane of a dicom

Tags: c#, dicom, clearcanvas

I am creating a dicom viewer using clear canvas library.
I need to find the image plane (axial, sagittal or coronal) of the dicom to implement triangulation.
My only hope was the Image Orientation tag (0020,0037), but some of the dicoms doesn't have that tag.

How can I find the plane from the dicom? Any help.

Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many modalities, the exact image orientation is neither available nor - for normal use of the created images - required. In these cases you can resort to Patient Orientation (0020,0020) to establish how to hang the images. This information is however by no means exact enough for what you are trying to do. OTOH, if the modality doesn't supply the image orientation tag, I doubt that the images produced by that modality, are suitable for your purposes.

Comment: All dicoms without Image Orientation tag (0020,0037) has got Patient Orientation tag (0020,0020).  
But, a few of them seems to have no value assigned for the patient orientaion tag.